# The translator API changes content of some tags in text/html mode

Tags: microsoft-translator

Using method “TranslateArray” of Microsoft Translator Text API with option “ContentType” mode “text/html”, changes content of some tags extracting part of “important” text out of the tag. 
This “changes” seems not justified by syntactic adjustments of the translation. 
An example translating from “EN” to “RU” 
Fragment of original text:

Download Program Name and discover the comfort of **managing advertising campaigns or sending messages to mobiles from your computer**.

Fragment of translated text:

Скачать Program Name и откройте для себя удобство **управления рекламных кампаний**или отправка сообщений на мобильные телефоны с вашего компьютера.

The text “или отправка сообщений на мобильные телефоны с вашего компьютера.” Equivalent of “or sending messages to mobiles from your computer” now is out strong tag. 
There is any way to force the api to respect the tags?

Answer (score 0):

there is only one way to influence the handling of tags, which is using contentType text/html vs. text/plain.
The words of the translation may be in very different order than the original, and the tags move around with the words they are attached to. The word the tag is attached to may appear a bit random occasionally.

In this particular case you get a better tag placement when using Microsoft Translator's neural decoder, invoked by &category=generalnn.
But at this time you will not want to switch to neural for heavily tagged content. As of right now, the tag placement is worse in neural, in most cases other than yours.